# How to show empty category in admin menus search

Tags: categories, menus, admin, search

[image]

[image]

This is the my screenshots please guide me that how to we can search empty category in admin menu.

Comment: Same behavior for the menu search in the Customizer. This seems like a bug to me, so I've created a ticket [#45298](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/45298). In the meanwhile one can add a filter for the corresponding `get_terms()` input arguments to add `'hide_empty' => false,`.

Answer (score 0):

Show empty category in admin menu search

```
//back
add_filter( 'get_terms_args', 'wpd_show_empty_terms_in_quick_search', 10, 2 );

function wpd_show_empty_terms_in_quick_search( $args, $taxonomies ){
    $args['hide_empty'] = false;
    return $args;
}
```