# Admin: WooCommerce Navigation Menus do not show empty categories search tab

Tags: menus, woocommerce-offtopic, search

I have been searching and finally found a question that answers my question:

[How to show empty category in admin menus search](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/302406/how-to-show-empty-category-in-admin-menus-search)

https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/45298

How could this be implemented as a quick fix? I am trying to build a complex WooCommerce menu but the search tab does not bring up empty categories which has become a pain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you perform a search for terms in the menu editor, it runs `get_terms()` with the `name__like` argument (a category is a type of "term").

The [`get_terms_args`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/get_terms_args/) filter lets you filter any use of `get_terms()`. So we can use this filter and check if the `name__like` argument has a value. If it does then that tells us this is a search for a term, in which case we will force the query to include empty terms:

```
function wpse_327345_search_empty_terms( $args, $taxonomies ) {
    if ( ! empty( $args['name__like'] ) ) {
        $args['hide_empty'] = false;
    }

    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'get_terms_args', 'wpse_327345_search_empty_terms', 10, 2 );
```

Note however that this will also affect searches for terms in other areas of the admin, like the post edit screen and categories list. If you *only* want to include empty terms when searching from the menu editor, you can check if the query is part of the AJAX request that performs the search by checking if `$_POST['action']` is exists and equals `menu-quick-search`:

```
function wpse_327345_search_empty_terms( $args, $taxonomies ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['action'] ) && $_POST['action'] === 'menu-quick-search' ) {
        if ( ! empty( $args['name__like'] ) ) {
            $args['hide_empty'] = false;
        }
    }

    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'get_terms_args', 'wpse_327345_search_empty_terms', 10, 2 );
```